# domain name display in shopify order page

Tags: shopify

We used shopify API library in our 2 php shopping website and moved all shopify products to these websites. Now our client wants to identify from which source shopify orders received in shopify order page. How to display the domain name as custom field in order page using API?

Answer (score 0):

While moving the products set the meta fields of product with domain name and  while placing that order generate array and push that value in meta fields or you can write the string and set it in the order note so you can easily populate the value.